# Как написать код так,что бы загружаемые в тг бота фото сохранялись,и пересылались пользователю по кнопке

Tags: python, aiogram

написал с горем пополам такого бота,но не знаю как дописать к нему,что если заканчиваются фото в папке,он не шел на второй круг,а останавливался на последней фото,и с возможностью пополнений фото\видео через того же бота,что бы пользователь по нажатию на получание фото\видео получал новые фото,начиная с той,с какой он закончил(написал очень по водяному,но надеюсь поймёте,гуглить я не умею,поэтому пишу за помощью сюда)

```
import os
import random

import aiogram.utils
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton

API_TOKEN = 'токен'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def welcome(message: types.Message):
    button_photo = KeyboardButton(' Рандомное фото')
    button_video = KeyboardButton(' Рандомное видео')
    keyboard_welcome = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(button_photo, button_video)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветик', reply_markup=keyboard_welcome)

p = 0
v = 0
@dp.message_handler(text=' Рандомное фото')
async def cmd_random_photo(message: types.Message):
    global p
    directory = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/tg/photo'
    photos = os.listdir(directory)
    if p >= len(photos):
        p = 0
    photo = photos[p]
    file = open(f"{directory}/{photo}", 'rb')
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=file)
    p += 1

@dp.message_handler(text=' Рандомное видео')
async def cmd_random_video(message: types.Message):
    global v
    directory = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/tg/video'
    videos = os.listdir(directory)
    if v >= len(videos):
        v = 0
    video = videos[v]
    file = open(f"{directory}/{video}", 'rb')
    await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video=file)
    
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

В конце цикла просто обнуляйте переменную, если последняя фотография p == количеству фотографий